# What is the correct datatype for an EWL-validated Phone Number field?

Tags: sql-server, types, enterprise-web-library

What should the data type of a phone number be in SQL Server? varchar? What length? And, where do I find this sort of information for EWL for similar fields (zip code, etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use `varchar` for phone numbers. I'd probably use something like `varchar(25)`. As far as I know there is no documentation on which SQL Server data type to use for each EWL data type. One thing you can do is look at the validation methods in the `Validator` class and see what they are capable of returning. I know that's not an ideal solution but I think it's your best bet right now.

Comment: Yeah there really needs to be a guide for how to set up a database to support each EWL feature.